# Flask - How to turn datetime JSON data from an API call into a "Last Seen X hours/minutes Ago"?

Tags: python, json, datetime, flask, python-datetime

I am using Flask and from an API call I am getting a datetime JSON data, I want to turn the datetime data into the "Hours ago" format, but I have no idea where to start.

This is the data that I am receiving from the API call:

```
{'first_seen': datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 12, 23, 50, 5, 989719),
 'last_seen': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 19, 9, 35, 4, 417316)
```

For example, I want the `"last_seen"` to translate to "Last Seen: 3 Hours Ago" or "Last Seen: 12 Days Ago".

The original API call:

```
    client = TwitchClient(app.config['TWITCH_CLIENT_ID'])
    users = client.users.translate_usernames_to_ids(streamer)

    streamers_page_list = []
    for user in users:
        streamer_channel_info = {
            'first_seen': user['created_at'],
            'last_seen': user['updated_at'],
            'name': user['display_name'],
            'bio': user['bio'],
            'logo': user['logo'],
            'id': user['id']
        }
        streamers_page_list.append(streamer_channel_info)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shouldn't be too hard actually. As you already have a `datetime` object you can get a `timedelta` object by subtracting your last_seen datetime from the current datetime.

From this `timedelta` object you can simply get the representative days, seconds or milliseconds as attributes.

Therefore you could basically do something like this:

```py
delta = datetime.datetime.now() - last_seen
if delta.days > 0:
    print("{} days ago".format(delta.days))
else:
     print("{} hours ago".format(int(delta.seconds / 3600)))
```

Answer (score 1):

extracting two datetime object from each other, will give you a timedelta object:

```
delta = datetime(2020, 8, 19, 9, 35, 4, 417316) - datetime(2014, 9, 12, 23, 50, 5, 989719)
delta
# output: 
# datetime.timedelta(days=2167, seconds=35098, microseconds=427597)
```

you can extract the days/seconds difference from timedelta object like this:

```
delta.days 
delta.seconds
```

Then you can reformat this info however you want.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest and cleanest way to do this is to use a library called [humanize](https://pypi.org/project/humanize/).

Pulling an example directly from the documentation:

```
>>> import humanize
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> humanize.naturalday(dt.datetime.now())
'today'
>>> humanize.naturaldelta(dt.timedelta(seconds=1001))
'16 minutes'
>>> humanize.naturalday(dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(days=1))
'yesterday'
>>> humanize.naturalday(dt.date(2007, 6, 5))
'Jun 05'
>>> humanize.naturaldate(dt.date(2007, 6, 5))
'Jun 05 2007'
>>> humanize.naturaltime(dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(seconds=1))
'a second ago'
>>> humanize.naturaltime(dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(seconds=3600))
'an hour ago'
```

In my opinion this is the best way to go. Submit the respective datetimes into `humanize.naturaltime()` and `humanize.naturalday()` and you'll be good to go!